# How to move all the files of a directory into multiple directories with a given number of files?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a directory containing more than 27000 images.

I want to split these files into folders each containing around 500 images.

It doesn't matter how they are sorted, I just want to separate them.

Comment: What have you tried so far? This is not a "give me the codez" site. You have to show that you've put in SOME effort at least.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following should work:

```sh
dest_base="destination"
src_dir="src/"

filesperdir=500
atfile=0
atdir=0
for file in $src_dir/*; do
    if ((atfile == 0)); then
        dest_dir=$(printf "$dest_base/%0.5d" $atdir)
        [[ -d $dest_dir ]] || mkdir -p $dest_dir
    fi
    mv $file $dest_dir
    ((atfile++))
    if ((atfile >= filesperdir)); then
        atfile=0
        ((atdir++))
    fi
done
```

Comment: This has the virtue of actually working, though if `$src_dir/*` is too long or if dest_base were configured to have a space in it or if any file had a space or other special characters in the name there would still be an issue.

Comment: Note: This is a bash script (not an sh script)

Answer (score 9):

A "simple" find / xargs would do:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | xargs -r -0 -P0 -n 500 sh -c 'mkdir newdir.$$; mv "$@" newdir.$$/' xx
```

Explanation:

- find

  - `-maxdepth 1` prevents find from recursively traversing any directories, safety, not needed if you know you don't have directories
  - `-type f` only find files
  - `-print0` separate files with null char instead of LF (to handle strange names)
- xargs

  - `-r` don't run with empty argument list
  - `-0` read files separated with null
  - `-P0` create as many processes as you need
  - `-n 500` run each process with 500 arguments
- sh

  - `-c` run command line script provided as next argument
  - `mkdir newdir.$$` make a new directory ending with the shell process PID
  - `mv "$@" newdir.$$/` move the arguments of the script (each of them quoted) to the newly created directory
  - `xx` name for the command line provided script (See sh manual)

Note that this is **not** something I would use in production, it's based mostly on the on the fact that `$$` (pid) will be different for each process executed by xargs

If you need the files sorted you can trow a `sort -z` between find an xargs.

If you want more meaningful directory names you can use something like this:

```
echo 1 >../seq
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 |sort -z | xargs -r -0 -P1 -n 500 sh -c 'read NR <../seq; mkdir newdir.$NR; mv "$@" newdir.$NR/; expr $NR + 1 >../seq' xx
```

- `echo 1 > ../seq` write the first directory suffix in a file (make sure it's not in the current directory)
- `-P1` tell xargs to run one command at a time to prevent race conditions
- `read NR <../seq` read the current directory suffix from the file
- `expr $NR + 1 >../seq` write the next directory suffix for the next run
- `sort -z` sort the files

Answer (score 0):

OK, the following solution stores temp files with lists of 500 file names. Adapt it as you need.
First we list all files in current dir, split 500 by 500, and store the results in outputXYZ.* files

```
ls | split -l 500 - outputXYZ.
# Then we go through all those files
count=0
for i in outputXYZ.*; do 
    ((count++))
    # We store the result in dir.X directory (created in current directory)
    mkdir dir.$count 2>/dev/null

    # And move those files into it 
    cat $i | xargs mv -t dir.$count

    # remove the temp file
    rm $i
done
```

At the end, you've got all your images in directories dir.1 (1..500), dir.2 (501..1000), dir.3, etc.

Comment: Buggy! Bad use of `ls`, unquoted `rm $i`(!), etc.

Comment: Hi, I don't get your "Bad us of ls" comment.

Comment: The output of `ls` is not reliable for any purpose other than human consumption. If you need a list of files in a reliable format you should use `find`. Parsing `ls` output will break on a large number of corner cases.

Comment: OK, searching through SO I've found that it's something you've already written, and found the link to the page explaining it (http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). I will read other articles on this site too. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You could start with this:

```
mkdir new_dir ; find source_dir | head -n 500  | xargs -I {} mv {} new_dir
```

This will create `new_dir` and move 500 files from `old_dir` to `new_dir`. You still have to manually invoke this for different values of `new_dir` until the old directory is empty, and you have to deal with file names that contain special characters.