# Sort and copy files from one directory to another via bash

Tags: linux, bash

I have about 4 million extension less files in one directory.

I need a bash script to copy them into another directory such that those files will be sorted into 1000 files per directory.

Eg.
source directory is `/temp/hugenooffiles/`

The file names are like `m_100, m_1005, m_10005`, etc.

destination directory is `/temp/sortedfiles/`

In the destination directory, a directory named 1 should be created containing files from `m_1` through `m_999`.

`directory 2` should be created containing files `m_1000` through `m_1999` and so on.

The destination files should be renamed to `1_m, 1000_m`, etc.

Also, if files in destination folder already exist then they should be overwritten.

Kindly help.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9085508/411882) answer...

Comment: Are you asking to write that script for you, or where the problem in your approach is? in the latter case, you have forgotten to paste your attempt. I'd like to say "fix your line 4, there's your problem" but without reference source, i can't

Comment: m_1 to m_999 is also just 999 files.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copy the first, second,.. 500 Files of a directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9082372/copy-the-first-second-500-files-of-a-directory)

Comment: @Bushmills I do not have any experience with shell scripting. I am a java developer. I have written a java code to do so but the sheer number of files is whacking the code. Hence, I thought a shell script might do the job. I am hoping for a little push in the right direction and I will try to improvise thereon.

Comment: @zplesivcak Thank you. I have some doubts though but I think man page might help.

Comment: yes, that's a problem which is rather suited for solving it using a shell script. Performance can be an issue, but bottleneck here isn't script interpretation, but file copying.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

SOURCE='/temp/hugenooffiles'
DEST='/temp/sortedfiles'

I=0
for FILE in "$SOURCE"/m_*; do
    (( D = 1 + ++I / 1000 ))
    [[ -d $DEST/$D ]] || mkdir -p "$DEST/$D"  ## You can just skip dir checking but that would be slow.
    cp -v "$FILE" "$DEST/$D/m_$I"
done
```

Note: By default pathname expansions in Bash (`"$SOURCE"/m_*`) are sorted.

Comment: Thank you. There is one additional change required. The folder into which the files will be copied depends upon what occurs after "m_". Eg. files named m_1 to m_999 should go into folder named 1, file named m_8677 will go into folder 9 while m_9000 will go into folder 10.

Answer (score 0):

I modified konsolebox's script and it did the job. Thank you.

```
> #!/bin/bash
> 
> SOURCE='/temp/hugenooffiles' 
> DEST='/temp/sortedfiles'
> 
> I=0 
> for FILE in "$SOURCE"/m_*;
> do
>     (( D = (( ${FILE#*_} / 1000 )) + 1 ))
>     [[ -d $DEST/$D ]] || mkdir -p "$DEST/$D"
>     mv -v "$FILE" "$DEST/$D/${FILE#*_}_m"
>     (( ++I )) 
> done
```